# Image from ImageSource

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, imagesource

I tried to follow the [following example](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21301/image-property-on-the-button) by @CraigDunn with the sample code

```
someButton.Image = ImageSource.FromFile("imageName.png");
```

My own try looks like this:

```
        _NavBarPrevPage = new Button
        {
            Image = ImageSource.FromResource("media_step_back.png")),
            BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
            TextColor = Color.White,
        };
```

For me, the IDE tells me:

```
The type Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource can't be converted to Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource. An explicit conversion exists. Perhaps a conversion is missing.
```

I think I'm doing exactely what @CraigDunn proposed.
What am I doing wrong?

I've tried the following, and I was able to get rid of the conversion errors in the current answer, but the image is not shown on the button, while it is shown in an image, so the file name is correct:

```
        var nImg = new FileImageSource()
        {
            File  = "media_step_back.png",
        };

        _NavBarPrevPage = new Button
        {
            Image =nImg,
        };
```

Comment: try someButton.Image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("imageName.png");

Comment: @PLOW This doesn't work as it 1) Image doesn't have "Source", and also Image expects to be of FileImageSource and not of ImageSource.

Comment: What you need is only a button with image? You are targeting iOS and/or Android platform?

Comment: @Janson I'm targetting all 3 platforms, and according to Craig Dunn's post I was expecting to get away with Xamarin.Forms.Button without platform specific code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the thing you need is a button with image that is implementing by code-behind :

```
Button button = new Button
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
                Font = Font.Default,
                FontSize = 10,
                TextColor = Color.White,
                HeightRequest = 35,
                WidthRequest = 80
            };

            button.Image = "media_step_back.png";

            this.Content = button;
```

Please remember to put the image file (media_step_back.png) in your target platform's resource folder

**UPDATE:**

You problem were you didn't add the image source in the Property folder and target platform's resource folder *(Please note that in below example, I have added a xamarin.png image in each Xamarin "Property" folder, Android's "Resource" and iOS's "Resource" folder)*

Below is the updated code that I placed the button into a StackLayout (which also able to works if without StackLayout) :

```
public class MainPageNew : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPageNew()
        {
            StackLayout parent = new StackLayout();
            Button button = new Button
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
                Font = Font.Default,
                FontSize = 10,
                TextColor = Color.White,
                HeightRequest = 300,
                WidthRequest = 80
            };

            //button.Image = "media_step_back.png";
            button.Image = "xamarin.png";

            parent.Children.Add(button);

            this.Content = parent;
        }
```

Android

[image]

iOS:

[image]

[This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iQxpTAkT47c83ol5HhtvIUqFT-7SmNk7) is the download link of the updated code.

Comment: @Jason It just doesn't show up for me. In my samples, I can show the image in a Xamarin.Forms.Image, but never in the button. I'm pretty sure I did it correctly. I've uploaded a sample project here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o2Szdi54jA15sS8zIPlA15WywkhtpXJG

Comment: Thank you. Could you post a screenshot of your button in UWP? Maybe that is my culprit. I'm always testing against UWP, and using your update code from Google Drive (thank you!), the image isn't shown in UWP. I've added "xamarin.png" to the UWP->Assets folder and set it as "Content". I also tried "Embedded Resource". None of it is working.

Comment: For Windows/UWP, you need to place images in the application's root directory with Build Action: Content, not the Asset folder. Asset folder is for the Application icon and SplashSceen image.

Comment: I just found out about that 1 minute ago, thank you so much for the really, really big help!

Comment: I never read that explicitely that Button.Image must be a file name of a file stored in the root for UWP, set to "Content" (and not "Embedded Resource"). Great to know now.

Comment: You are welcome! UWP is a bit weird but that is how it works.

Comment: Hope this link will be helpful if you need to deal with a large amount of image in UWP project. Otherwise dump all images (imagine if 100++ images) in root folder will be a mess. (http://dkdevelopment.net/2017/07/20/xamarin-forms-uwp-image-path/)

Comment: There's no built-in way to have the image auto-size, right?

Comment: Not sure but maybe you can try to manipulate the button “HorizontalOptions”? Or create another question since it is a bit  off topic? :)